# Join on the column that doesn't equal a value

Tags: postgresql

I have a friends table

| id | requestor | requestee | status |

requestor and requestee are both userIds

I want to get a list of friends that a user has, and joining the user who isnt them.

Since they can either be the requestor or requestee or a friend request, Ive done something like this

```
select * from friends where requestor = 4 or requestee = 4
```

where 4 is the id of the user making the query.
I would like something like this

```
join users on ( function([requstor, requestee], 4) ) = users.id
```

Some sort of function to pass both columns and it will return the column that doesnt equal 4, does this exist in postgresql?

Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just add a `users.id <> 4` condition (in either the join or the where clause):

```
select *
from friends
join users on users.id in (requestor, requestee) and users.id <> 4
where requestor = 4 or requestee = 4
```